# PDO Prepared stament while in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

This is something simple but I am having a really difficult time with it for some reason.
Basically, I do a select statement to find results. I loop through that result and update the items I found in result.

This is my code:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from licenses where email='empty' limit $quantity");
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("update licenses set email=:em, exp_date=:exp where 'id'=:id");

    foreach ($row as $row)
    {
        $expires = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('+365 days'));
        $license = $row['license_key'];
        $lid = $row['id'];

        echo $license . '<br> ID:' . $lid;

        $stmt->bindValue(':em', $email1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':exp', $expires, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $lid, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

This code WORKS, it updates my database in a working condition. However, the website returns a 504 error and the output of license does not get displayed. Does anyone know what is wrong with this code or how can I complete the task I am aiming for?

** Edit: When I use fiddler, I get this error: 
[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

Comment: From php manual `Note: Some drivers require to close cursor before executing next statement.` http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php . What driver do you use?

Comment: I have even tried closing cursor before doing a second prepare. No luck either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I cant believe we all missed this one. In your update query you use expression `'id'=:id` in where clause. This effectively means that if your $id is say 15 -> 'id' != 15 and query will never update any values in table. Remove the quotes around `id`:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("update licenses 
            set email=:em, exp_date=:exp where id=:id");
```

Comment: Great observation!!! That was actually one of the reason it was causing an error. I figured that one out already while testing. 

Another reason the error was happening was because of: array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)); I had to remove that and it was working again.

Answer (score 3):

change variable name `$row` to `$rows`

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // change variable $row to $rows
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  // Your Code
}
```